# npm "404 @npmcli/docs@^1.0.0 is not in this registry"

Tags: npm

I am currently running into an odd error trying to setup nodejs/npm (Windows 10 22H2, nodejs v20.5.1, npm v9.8.1).
Trying to install any package (initially the error popped up with `ipfs-car` but any other package even with `npm install`) yields the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@npmcli%2fdocs - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@npmcli/docs@^1.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Error mentions I can install the package from a local or online archive but after searching for this package I could not find any info about it anywhere, as if it never existed. But npm wants me to install it and I'm completely locked.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue and also can't find any solution for that - have you been able to find a fix for that yet?

Comment: did you try to update to the latest node and npm version? For me the error seems to be gone now